# Counting left to right maxima in permutations in Sage

Tags: permutations

I'd like to count the number of left to right maxima in a permutation in Sage/Python, i.e. the number of times a number appears in the permutation that is greater than all of the previous numbers. The first number will always count as a maxima. I'm struggling with how to formulate the 'if' statement to include all previous numbers in the permutation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Find an alternative condition using just one known value.

Comment: Coding questions are typically off-topic here.  Any community votes (via vote-to-close)?

Comment: Find an $O(n)$ algorithm, you should keep track of the greatest number so far, and the number of times this is superseded.